# Date search criteria in entries page in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I’m trying to enable a date related search filter in entries page and I keep getting this error message:

> value is not properly formatted

Since I use a simple expression (date is...or date is before...), I suppose this is a glitch.

Is this the case? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My name is Parker, I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com). The date based searches on the Entries page must be in the US based format, regardless of the localization settings of the form. Unfortunately, for certain date/time formats the date picker control on the search criteria dialog does not handle this properly.

We are currently working on a fix for this, in the meantime you can switch over to the Advanced Editor for the search criteria and enter a valid US date and the search should work as expected.[image]